# Using Javascript (<script> and onload) with Ajax Calls

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, onload

I wrote a previous question...which was rather confusing...so I have made this as simple as possible for everyone to understand.

I am using the **PHP Built-In Web Server** to test my PHP code.  I don't know if there is any downside to this but that is what I am using at the moment (Advice would be helpful in regards to this as I evidently don't know what I'm doing, but I don't think it pertains to the problem)

I am trying to run the below code and specifically `leggo()`.  **Any scripts** in `page2.php` do not work and **onloads definitely don't work** (for obvious reasons).  These scripts not working is strange, but when all the scripts are moved into `header.php` they begin to work...**except onload's**.  Is there an **alternative to using onload**.  I'm guessing there is a **problem with using AJAX and onload in conjunction**. ---EDIT--- Code has been simplified for better understanding and per suggestion.

**Code**

*heading.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function loadPageBelow(fileName) {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", fileName, true);
                xhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><b>THIS IS THE HEADER</b></p>
        <a onclick="loadPageBelow('page2.php')">Click to goto page 2</a>
        <div id="content">
            <?php
                include("starter.html");
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*starter.html*

```
<p>Welcome to the homepage</p>
```

*page2.php*

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="200px" height="200px">HI</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script>
    leggo();
</script>
```

*script.js*

```
function leggo()
{
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
}
```

To run Web Server as I am doing go to the folder with the programs and type `php -S localhost:8000` into the terminal.  Then go the browser and type `http://localhost:8000/heading.php`

---------------------------------------EDIT---------------------------------------

I made the AJAX call use jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("a").click(function() {
                $("#content").load("page2.php");
            });
        });
```

And now I get the error:

***Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.***

Which may be something else.  Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: innerHTML used for adding HTML to the page is fine, but if it contains JavaScript, it won't execute, or at least cross-browser if it does.  jQuery uses a workaround for it which hasn't really failed for me in my tests. Try for yourself: `$('body').append('<script>alert("hi");</script>');`

Comment: Where would that line go in the code.  Im rather new to all this stuff.  Also why would calling the script from jQuery be any different from calling it with plain js. - @Ultimater

Comment: jQuery filters the HTML first, stripping out JavaScript, saving it in the process, before it appends the HTML on the page, then evaluates the javascript it stripped out. Whatever workaround they wrote in jQuery has yet to fail me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand why you want to include HTML pages with JavaScript. This is not very usual and there are probably other ways to do this. In any case if you insist on doing this you need to make sure, especially when doing this that you don't have a full document. So `starter.html` should look more like this:

```
        <p>Welcome to the homepage</p>
```

And `page2.php` should look more like this:

```
    <script>
        function leggo() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
        }
    </script>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="200px" height="200px">HI</canvas>
    <script>
        leggo();
    </script>
```

Then you should add a call to the `leggo()` at in `xhttp.onreadystatechange` of `loadPageBelow` like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function loadPageBelow(fileName) {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", fileName, true);
                xhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><b>THIS IS THE HEADER</b></p>
        <a onclick="loadPageBelow('page2.php')">Click to goto page 2</a>
        <div id="content">
            <?php
                include("starter.html");
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Those files are pasted into the files I have and I still get an error "Can't find variable: leggo" - @NicolasBouvrette

Comment: @Jetstream5500 you are right, callback would not work given the function does not exist. I have updated with an other solution which does not require callback.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work.  Ill edit the question with what I have now so everyone is on the same page.  If there is another way to do the Ajax that might be helpful as well?  Little lost as it seems like a simple task - @NicolasBouvrette

Comment: @Jetstream5500 I honestly didn't test but it should be very close to be working. Do you see any error in your console? Do you see the script and Canvas when using Chrome's inspection?

Comment: The canvas definitely is there because I can add a border and it expands...just nothing draws.  No errors in safari...dont know how to use chrome inspection but it looks as though it doesn't have the script for whatever reason but not sure - @NicolasBouvrette

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just loading content in the innerHTML of a div where the **body has already been loaded** , you should remove the  and  tags from starter.hml and page2.php . Also your script should be placed under all of your html markup . After you have done this , to initialize your leggo() function just add a document ready check.

**Example**

```
<script>

function leggo() {
                var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
                ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
  }

if(document.readyState == "complete"){

leggo()


}
</script>
```

Comment: I included that 'if statement' in the JS file and it still doesn't work (pasted).  I'm assuming that would be the same affect as having it in in the tag so..no go? - @KpTheConstructor

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb and assume your HTML is not parsed and the `leggo()` function is searching for canvas with id of canvas. That element is not written yet as page is interpreting the response.

I'm not going to criticize your codes. I would suggest you to defer the script until the page loads in web browser. To do this, separate your `leggo()` function from HTML and into external JavaScript file then update the HTML `<script>` tag to include `defer` and `src` attributes.

If external script is not possible, I would suggest including jQuery onload function to detect whether contents have loaded.

If jQuery is not possible, then I would suggest following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/800010/5012277) to detect whether contents are loaded without using jQuery.

Suggested Alternative:
`heading.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function loadPageBelow(fileName) {
            this.document.location = "http://localhost/heading.php?page="+fileName;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><b>THIS IS THE HEADER</b></p>
    <a onclick="loadPageBelow('page2.php')">Click to goto page 2</a>
    <div id="content">
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
                include($_GET['page']);
            } else {
                include("starter.html");
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <canvas id="canvas" width="200px" height="200px">HI</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer>

This code still gives the same error - @jmsweb

Comment: I'm rather curious whether `page2.php` is loaded correctly. Could you try update to absolute URL for `page2.php` instead of passing a file name, i.e., `loadPageBelow('http://localhost:8000/page2.php')` or navigating to `http://localhost:8000/page2.php` and let us know what happened?

Comment: It shows the canvas working...as expected, but there is no header and when u pass 'http://localhost:8000/page2.php' to loadPageBelow it crashes...as expected? - @jmsweb

Comment: Actually neither of the tests crash just they can't draw in the canvas (I made a typo) - @jmsweb

Comment: I'm sorry, I would have to change your structure to include files without calling AJAX because scripts cannot be executed through AJAX. This is my suggested alternative to your current structure.

Comment: So if I change the structure so it just includes a header.php and footer.php for each subpage (allowing for refresh of pages), how do I do the subpage thing (aka index.php?page=home) - @jmsweb

Comment: I'll just have to deal with the page refresh rn I guess.  By doing includes and just linking between pages the code works.  I'll leave the question up for a little bit to see if there are any other ideas as to prevent page refresh - @jmsweb

Comment: If page refresh is a concern then you could modify the JavaScript to execute `e.preventDefault();` on submission. Although that is not the ideal solution especially as HTML templating.